# While loop to check uniqueness of custom id

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I have a MongoDB databse set up with some objects that have a unique code (not the primary key).
I should also note that I'm using NodeJS and this code is in my server.js to connect to the MongoDB database.

To generate a new code, I generate one randomly and I want to check if it already exists. If not then we use it no problem, but if it already exists I want to generate another code and check it again. This is the code I use to check if the id already exists:

```
function createPartyId(callback) {
    var min = 10000, max = 99999;
    var partyId = -1, count = -1;
    async.whilst(
        function () { return count != 0; },
        function (callback) {
            partyId = min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
            partyId = 88888;
            getPartyIdCount(partyId, function(num) {
                count = num;
            });
        },
        function (err) {

        }
    );
}

function getPartyIdCount(partyId, callback) {
    count = -1;
    db.db_name.find({id: partyId}, function(err, records) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("There was an error executing the database query.");
            callback(count);
        }
        count = records.length;
        callback(count);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your actual implementation of getExistingCount() please?

Comment: I updated my main post with the code

Comment: I think something may be wrong with the find function that returns undefined

Comment: You're returning `records.length` from your anonymous callback function, not from `getPartyIdCount` (which returns `undefined`).  Async functions can't return their results, they need to use callbacks.

Comment: I tried to do it with a callback, but still no luck cause it seems to skip over it (see main code)

Comment: You need to replace your `do...while` with its async equivalent.  See [`async.doWhilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#dowhilstfn-test-callback).

Comment: Hmm I tried to implement it but still not luck...

Comment: You need to invoke the callback that gets passed into your second function in the whilst call, otherwise async never knows you're done and won't run the loop.

Comment: You're using whilst wrong. You need to invoke the callback function passed to the fn parameter to tell async to run the next iteration of the loop. But it doesn't matter since async.whilst does not block. It kicks off the iteration but nothing actually happens yet. In the meantime your function returns. There's no way to actually return the result back as written. An async function must use a callback to return the value, not the return value from the function.

Comment: I updated my code again, and indeed the loop runs but a result is returned anyway. I'm really stuck, are you saying what I want is impossible? I only want to check the ID against the database a couple of times how hard can that be, sigh..

Comment: See my new answer - you never actually invoke the callback you pass into getPartyId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Expanding my comment from above)

The issue is that createPartyId is an asynchronous function, but you're trying to return the value synchronously. That won't work. Once you touch an async operation, the rest of the call stack has to be async as well.

You don't include the code that's calling this, but I assume you want it to be something like:

```
var partyId = createPartyId();
// do stuff...
```

That's not going to work. Try this:

```
function createPartyId(callback) {
    var min = 10000, max = 99999;
    var partyId = -1, count = -1;
    async.whilst(
        function () { return (count == 0); },
        function (callback) {
            partyId = min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
            partyId = 88888;
            getPartyIdCount(partyId, function(err, num) {
                if (!err) {
                    count = num;
                }
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        function (err) {
          // this is called when the loop ends, error or not
          // Invoke outer callback to return the result
          callback(err, count); 
        }
    );
}

function getPartyIdCount(partyId, callback) {
    count = -1;
    db.db_name.find({id: partyId}, function(err, records) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("There was an error executing the database query.");
            callback(err);
        }
        count = records.length;
        callback(null, count);
    });
}
```

(I've also adopted the default node.js convention of always returning errors as the first argument to callback functions.)

So, to use this you would do:

```
getPartyId(function (err, num) {
    if (err) { return aughItFellOver(err); }

    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, it was really tricky for a first timer with all these asynchronous callbacks. You're the best!

Comment: @Chris Tavares It works perfect man :) Thanks for the answer +1

Answer (score 3):

First of all, is there any particular reason you're not using a simple number increment sequence?  This type of code is prone to inefficiency, the more numbers you generate the more chance you have of collisions which means you're going to be spending more time on generating an ID for your data than you are on the rest of your processing.  Not a good idea.

But I can still tell you what's going wrong.

OK, so `getPartyIdCount()` will only, ever, always, without fail, return undefined (or, basically, nothing).

Your mongo call processes the return value in a callback, and that callback doesn't assign its value to anything, so `return records.length` just gets lost into nothingness.

You've mixed up `createPartyId()`, which it appears you want to run synchronously, with your mongo call, which must run asynchronously.

`return` always goes with the *nearest* containing `function`, so in this case it goes with `function(err, records)`, not `function getPartyIdCount(partyId)`.

Comment: I don't want to add a simple counter because I need it to be semi-random. And If a user gets a code that is, say 11111, then he can guess 11112 or 11110. I've updated my code in the main post but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I obviously don't know your application, but... so what?  He can guess 11112 anyway, and it might just be a valid ID even though they are assigned randomly.  If you need it to be practically unguessable, then you need a random string of bytes, not just a random number.  If you need it to be truly unguessable, you need to use a CSPRNG.  But more likely, you need to build your application so that guessing other IDs doesn't expose a weakness.